# Missing "org" and "com" packages in Java under Ubuntu 12.04 in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7

After installing the java openjdk-6-* and netbeans apt packages onto my computer, i'm unable to compile or run any java source file in Netbeans 7.0, i always get following messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist
    at myproject.MyProjectSurface.initComponents(MyProjectSurface.java:34)
    at myproject.MyProjectSurface.<init>(MyProjectSurface.java:21)
    at myproject.MyProject.main(MyProject.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

This only happens when i want to create for example a JFrame Form or anything that would use the packages mentioned in the title.
What is the problem here?

Comment: *Any* source file? I find that unlikely, unless something is very broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "org.jdesktop.*" packages are not part of a standard Java installation.  You have to download the relevant JARs from somewhere and add them to your project.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm going to give it a try